# Android listview change item selected state in adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have `ListView` with single choice mode. I make set selection when the user clicks on a list item and it works. Now I need to:

1. make set selection when the user clicks on the play button in `ListView` item.
2. do it in my `ListView` adapter.
3. unselect the previous item and select the item where the user clicked on the play button.

I tried a few different solutions and they do not work.
In some case I make multi-select and in some cases I can't select an item.
[image]

> xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/menu_list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listen_price_button"
    android:background="@color/rose"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="11dp"
    android:paddingRight="11dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    />
```

> Selection code used in activity (works fine)

```
// handle click on list view item
listMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        view.setSelected(true);
        setDetailsData(position);
        mSelectedPosition = position;
    }
});
```

> play button code in adapter

```
viewHolder.playImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Listen currentItem = mListenList.get(position);
            if (currentItem.isPurchased() || currentItem.isFree()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ListenDetailActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("listen_item", currentItem);
                intent.putExtra("listen_list", mListenList);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                try {
                    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow((Activity) mContext, currentItem.getSku(), 1001,
                            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
                } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error launching purchase flow. Another async operation in progress.");
                }
            }
        }
});
```

what I tried to add on play button and it do not work

```
 list.clearChoices();
    list.requestLayout();
    finalConvertView.setSelected(true);
```

if i add only  `finalConvertView.setSelected(true);` it make multiselect

also i tried to unselect all then to select one but it also do not work

```
 for ( int i=0; i< list.getCount(); i++ ) {

                   list.setItemChecked(i, false);

  }
finalConvertView.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean that your playImage didn't work? Try to add this following in XML for 'playImage'

```
android:focusable="false"
```

also try to add this:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

on the top level layout of item on listview.

Comment: my image works but i cant make setselection of whole itemview when i click on play button.

Comment: From click listener, you try to use: ((ListView)parent).setItemChecked(position, true) to set the current item on ListView